# Как бороться с предупреждением о null?

Tags: c#

Как вы обычно обходите данные предупреждения? Я просто гарантирую, что Name точно не будет name, я его проверяю с помощью FluentValidation, обычно я просто вырубаю это, но это не самый лучший способ)

Собственно предупреждение:
Свойство не допускающий значение null должен содержать отличное от null при выходе из конструктора

```
public record CreateCatalogBrandRequest : IRequest<CreateCatalogBrandResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class CreateCatalogBrandRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateCatalogBrandRequest>
{
    public CreateCatalogBrandRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Name field is required")
            .MaximumLength(255)
            .WithMessage("The maximum length of the Name field is 255 characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: `public string Name { get; set; }  = null!` или `public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty`

Comment: `RuleFor(x => x.Name!)`

Comment: Я например вообще не воспринимаю nullable предупреждения и отключаю их в csproj файле, удаляю `<Nullable>` параметр. Мне хватает навыка писать нормальный код без этих предупреждений вообще.

Comment: С ними не надо бороться, их надо понимать! Вот о чем говорит предупреждение? О том, что этот объект может быть `null`, а значит, если обратиться к нему, будет ошибка. Сделайте проверку на `null` этого объекта, пропадет и предупреждение, а код станет безопасней. Ок, скажете "Но я хочу, чтобы там был null" - без проблем, сделайте тип `Nullable`, просто добавьте в конце типа вопросительный знак (прим: `string?`), IDE поймет, что в этом методе допускается дальше `null`. А если скажете "Ну я уверен, что тут не может быть NULL" -  поставьте воскл. знак, IDE будет игнорировать это место (`null!`).